# CMake INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION for Debug only targets

Tags: xcode, cmake

I have a project which I build both as Debug, Release, and RelWithDebInfo. Starting in CMake 3.9.6 (I think?), the property `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION` has been introduced, which includes -flto for the project. However, I don't want to have -flto enabled when compiling for Debug, as it slows down the compile time (and the debugger is less stable in my experience when this feature is enabled).

Currently what I do to enable -flto in CMake is the following:

```
include(CheckIPOSupported)
check_ipo_supported(RESULT ipo_result OUTPUT ipo_err)
if (ipo_result)
    message(STATUS "IPO is supported")
    set_property(GLOBAL PROPERTY INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION TRUE)
endif ()
```

I wonder whether there's an option to include this feature only when Release is enabled.
Moreover, I'm using the Xcode generator with my project, so I wonder whether this rule (-flto for Debug configuration only) can be applied to the generated .xcodeproj as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `INTERPROCEDURAL_OPTIMIZATION_<CONFIG>` instead. Note that these are directory and target properties not global.  So you'll have to enable it for the configurations that do use it or you may be able set it to false to deactivate it if enabled.

Comment: Thanks. Additional, for future reference, it is possible to `set(_CMAKE_LTO_THIN TRUE)` if one wants to use ThinLTO.